# Get list of cities within a bounding box

Tags: web-service, reverse-geocoding, geocoding

I need to find a web service that allows me to reverse-geocode but with a bounding box. In other words, I want to give the coordinates for a bounding box of latitude and longitude, and be provided with a list of cities.

Comment: I've not heard this referred to as reverse geocoding - it sounds like a selection of features by rectangle.

Comment: Google Maps Api v3 (using bounds) http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?city&bounds=34.172684,-118.604794|34.236144,-118.500938&sensor=false

Comment: What have you already looked at? What have you tried? What worked? What didn't work, and what happened instead? What are your constraints? What are your goals? Have you looked at Overpass API from openstreetmap: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API